# how to pass git credentials to multiscm closure via environment variable

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I'm having a hard time trying to pass git credentials via the `credentialParam` drop down.
Whenever I run a job generated from the code below (I select the correct deploy key from a drop-down), git says it is does not accept credentials (it returns `Permission denied (publickey).`)
When I explicitly hardcode git deploy key's id in the 'credentials' closure, everything works just fine.
I'm wondering why it's not being picked from the `REPO_CREDENTIALS` variable?
It is also weird because whenever I change the git url manually before running the generated job, the change is immediately picked by the job, even though it is passed via an environment variable as well.

Thanks

```
job("test-job") {    


    parameters {
        stringParam('GIT_URL', 'git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git', 'URL or Github repository for the project')
        credentialsParam('REPO_CREDENTIALS') {
            type('com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey')
            required(true)
            defaultValue('')
            description('Credential to use to pull from Github for this project')
        }
        stringParam('GIT_BRANCH', 'master', 'Git branch to scan, without \'origin/\' prefix.')
    }




    multiscm {
        git {
            remote {
                url('$GIT_URL')
                credentials('$REPO_CREDENTIALS')
            }
            branches('$GIT_BRANCH')
        }
    }


    steps {
        shell('./run.sh')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use a credentials parameters as Git SCM credentials. The Git plugin does not support variable expansion for that field. It's not possible configure a variable as Git credentials in the config UI as well. Job DSL can only do generate config that the UI can generate. If a feature is not available in the config UI, then it's also not available in Job DSL.